# Showing Django Admin actions on template

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm currently building a dashboard for my project and I would like the admin or super user to be able to see all the actions that have been down so far, sort of like an activity log.

For example:

User A has created a new project object

Is there any way to pull the django admin actions and place them on a template (my dashboard.html)?

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction that would be a great help.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: [AuditTrail (with a simple patch for fixture imports)](https://github.com/LaundroMat/django-AuditTrail/network) might be a good starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLs:

```
(r'^dashboard$', 'dashboard_view'),
```

View:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
def dashboard_view(request):
    log = LogEntry.objects.select_related().all().order_by("id")
    return render_to_response("app_name/dashboard.html", {'log': log},)
```

Template:

```
{% for l in log %}
<p>
    {{ l.id }} {{ l.user.username }} {{ l.change_message }}
</p>

{% endfor %}
```

There's an extension [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/master/README.markdown) it allows to keep track of all changes made to models not only actions in admin interface. It also allows to rollback the model to any point in time.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex.  I've noticed the log only shows admin side changes,  do you know any methods to extend that to when something is changed client side?

Comment: I think you problem can be solved by django-reversion (http://goo.gl/sefPv). It will allow you to track all changes made to the model.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will look into this for sure.